# How To See SQLite Database in my Chrome / Firefox Browser?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I am Using `SQLite` database in my Android App. I want to See the database in my chrome or Firefox browser .

To See the Database , normally i Open `Logcat` in android Studio and select verbose and write `http` in `serach` box then it provides me a Link to Open Database in my browser

> Like : D/DebugDB: Open http://192.168.2.116:8083 in your browser

But in my new project it is not showing the link . What should i do?

Comment: Anybody knows about this?

Comment: use stetho library.

Comment: for this you have to install firefox sqlite manager plugin in firefox browser and open your android db file in this.

Comment: refer this link : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e14021/know-where-database-is-stored-in-android-studio/

Comment: @Android Team thanks , i already checked that , but problem is there is no database file available .

Normally i open logcat then select verbose then write http in searcch box then it will provide me a link to open database in my browser but it not working in my new project , do u know abt that?

Comment: @Basi Please give an upvote i got banned from asking new questions and i don't see how my questions are un-relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple libs to achieve this

1. [Android-Debug-Database](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database)
2. [stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/)

please refer link for initialization in your app

Comment: thanks a lot this is exactly the Answer i am looking for .

Comment: welcome , please give an upvote on my questions because i got banned from asking more questions and i don't see why my questions are not relavent .
@Basi

Answer (score 1):

you need to use Stetho library, which will show you your db via ur browser. you can track network request as well. see this here -> [Stetho](https://github.com/facebook/stetho)

Comment: @JayDanger thanks not the answer i am looking for but this helped too . it is working .

Comment: how does this is not your answer? i mean other than seeing your sqlite db what do you want? this will even work wirelessly as well.

Comment: yes i said this helped too . and it is working for me . i wanted to see like "Basi" answered but thanks this is Good too .

Comment: pleasure @JayDangar

Comment: Please give and upvote because i got banned from asking new questions and i don't se how my questions are irrelevant @Jay

Answer (score 0):

You can get the db from

```
View -> Tools Window -> Device File Explorer
```

[image]

Save this...

[Install this and open the file](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)

Comment: Thanks , i checked but there is no database file for me . should i have to set the location or it is bydefault?

Comment: No need. are you sure the db is created.

Comment: @DVK yes i am fetching the records in list and all the records are available , i want to see it in my chrome / firefox browser . 

Normally i open logcat then select verbose then write http in searcch box then it will provide me a link to open database in my browser but it not working in my new project , do u know abt that?

Comment: I usually do the above method.